# How to fix "failed to sync gradle project"

Tags: android

I'm trying to build a CM12 theme so I followed this guide:https://github.com/cyngn/android_packages_themes_Template/blob/cm-12.0/README.md
But when I want to sync the gradle,it gives error. Eve I enabled offline mode but it didn't help at all.
Here is a pic:http://8pic.ir/images/5ywgjmaowevu6qiky6x4.jpg

Comment: did your problem got resolve ?

Comment: your internet is on when you build your project?

Comment: Yes, you suggest to turn it off then try?

Comment: have you enable your offline work in android studio ?

Comment: or try my edited answer and Let me know

Comment: If you mean gradle offline mode,yes.

Comment: ok try edited new answer

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

In your Android Studio Go to `File -> Setting -> HTTP Proxy - check No proxy` option and then build again.

**OR**

Using the local Gradle environment:

Ctrl + Alt + S to open the settings, select the Gradle entry, the radio "use local gradle distribution" and specify your Gradle installation path.

It might be solve your problem. Thank you

Comment: Thank you.But it was check by default.

Comment: I have tried this before but no success,anyway I try it again.thank you

Comment: ok then clean your project and then sync it might work because its all work for me when i m getting this type of error